# Is time a finite resource?

Tags: time

I am struggling to find an answer for this question because time as we know it would *end* when we reach the [heat death of a universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe). Which would imply that is the end of time.

I think I have a misunderstanding that time ends when the heat death happens.

So, is time a finite resource when the end of the universe happens, or would it just keep going even after that point?

Comment: From a physics point of view the heath death of the universe is the result of an oversimplified model of the universe as a closed system with a preferred scale. You can get rid of it in different ways, all of which will lead you outside of conventional physics, though. I would file this question under "philosophy of physics" rather than physics proper.

Comment: @Traven : why don't you ask a question about time and the beginning of the universe?

Comment: Yeah, boss, I know I said I'd have it done by this morning, but where was I supposed to find the time.  Jones here used it all up!

Comment: @John Duffield: I think the same concept would apply when the universe was created and when it would *end*. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I think they're pretty different Traven. Not that anybody really knows any answers either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming general relativity is a valid way to describe the universe, *time* is just a coordinate like the three spatial coordinates. There is no reason to suppose that the time coordinate has a limit i.e. time increases continuously and without limit into the future.

The only way that the time coordinate may have a limit is if the geometry of the universe has a future singularity. In that case we can't continue the time coordinate past the singularity. However, unless some radically new physics turns up there is no reason to suppose our universe has a future singularity.

The heat death will certainly make it hard to measure time. A clock, like any mechanism, relies on a free energy gradient to function, and as the universe approaches the hear death all free energy gradients will disappear. But this does not mean that time stops, only that there is no longer any way to measure it.

Comment: I have to object to a dangerous suggestion that seems to plague beginners a lot. Even in general relativity time is not "just a coordinate", it is a very special coordinate which is very different from the three spatial coordinates. This is physically evident in the way we construct clocks vs. rulers. A proper analysis of the interplay between time and space would immediately bring thermodynamics into the equation (clocks are local thermodynamic machines), Einstein simply failed to mention this in his papers and we still don't teach this early enough IMHO, causing unnecessary confusion.